# Got error while testing App - Firebase Test Lab

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-test-lab, gson

I just cannot understand what error is this. I got it when I tried to test my app on a device from the Firebase Test Lab. When I test the app on my phone and on the android emulator in Android Studio, everything works fine, but here, at the first activity created, I get this error that I don't know what means. If you know the problem, or how to solve it, please help me out. Thanks

[image: Error from Firebase Test Lab phone]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.6'

implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is ProGuard enabled for your build?

Comment: @BobSnyder , no it wasn't, but now I am getting another errors when building the signed apk file. "can't find superclass or interface", "can't find referenced class", are the errors...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please join the #test-lab channel at https://firebase-community.slack.com  and then post a sample matrix-id of a test with this failure? A new Firebase Test Lab bug was filed a couple days ago that might be the same as this, but we can't tell without inspecting your test matrix.

Comment: I will try to do that. Thanks